# How to properly call multiple environment variables within a variable definition in Node

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I have two environment variables that I have saved in my local local.env.js file. I'd like to use them in place of the username and password in the following code:

```
var admins = {
  'frank': { password: 'mypassword' },
   };
```

When I use the code below, I get an error (`Unexpected token .`):

```
var admins = {
    process.env.BASIC_AUTH_USER: {password: process.env.BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD},
    };
```

Any suggestions on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES5 and earlier, a static object declaration cannot use a "computed" value for a property name - it must be a string literal.  So, you have to use an actual line of code to assign the property using the `obj[computedPropName] = value;` syntax.  In your specific case, that would look like this:

```
var admins = {};
admins[process.env.BASIC_AUTH_USER] = {password: process.env.BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD};
```

---

In ES6, you can use a computed value in a static declaration if you enclose it in the array syntax like this:

```
var admins = {[process.env.BASIC_AUTH_USER]: {password: process.env.BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD}};
```

See [this description of new ES6 features](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals) and [this MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_6) for some further description of this feature.

Portions of ES6 are available in some of the latest version of browsers, in runtime environments like node.js and, of course, you can use transpilers to code in ES6, but transpile to ES5 compatible code for many features.  We are, of course, a ways away from being able to rely on native ES6 support for general cross browser use (thus the interest in transpilers now).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array-like-notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/), like so:

```
var admins = {};

admins[process.env.BASIC_AUTH_USER] = {
    password: process.env.BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD
};
```

If `BASIC_AUTH_USER` is `"Frank"` and `BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD` is "potatosalad" then you will end up with an object like this:

```
admins: {
    Frank: {
        password: 'potatosalad'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`admins = {};
admins[process.env.BASIC_AUTH_USER] = {password: process.env.BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD};`